# security incident or valid homebrew jobs? What's this cc1 process?

Tags: terminal, command-line, security, homebrew, gcc

On my iMac the fans get very loud and with top I saw that processes named `cc1` took very much CPU.

Can you explain me this processes? Security incident?

```
> ps -ef | grep cc1
  503 38350 38348   0  7:19PM ??         0:00.32 /private/tmp/gcc-20160805-32134-1wpoevg/gcc-6.1.0/build/./gcc/cc1 -quiet -I . -I . -I ../../.././gcc -I ../../../../libgcc -I ../../../../libgcc/. -I ../../../../libgcc/../gcc -I ../../../../libgcc/../include -imultilib i386 -iprefix /private/tmp/gcc-20160805-32134-1wpoevg/gcc-6.1.0/build/gcc/../lib/gcc/6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/6.1.0/ -isystem /private/tmp/gcc-20160805-32134-1wpoevg/gcc-6.1.0/build/./gcc/include -isystem /private/tmp/gcc-20160805-32134-1wpoevg/gcc-6.1.0/build/./gcc/include-fixed -MD subtf3.d -MF subtf3.dep -MP -MT subtf3.o -D__DYNAMIC__ -D IN_GCC -D IN_LIBGCC2 -D HAVE_CC_TLS -D USE_EMUTLS -D HIDE_EXPORTS -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.1.0_1/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/include -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.1.0_1/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/sys-include -isystem ./include ../../../../libgcc/soft-fp/subtf3.c -fPIC -feliminate-unused-debug-symbols -quiet -dumpbase subtf3.c -m32 -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -mtune=core2 -auxbase-strip subtf3.o -g -g -g -O2 -O2 -O2 -Wextra -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-type-limits -fbuilding-libgcc -fno-stack-protector -fno-common -fvisibility=hidden -o -
  503 38358 38356   0  7:19PM ??         0:00.00 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -cc1as -triple i386-apple-macosx10.11.0 -filetype obj -main-file-name - -target-cpu yonah -dwarf-version=2 -fdebug-compilation-dir /private/tmp/gcc-20160805-32134-1wpoevg/gcc-6.1.0/build/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/i386/libgcc -dwarf-debug-producer Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31) -mrelocation-model pic -o subtf3.o -
  503 38518 38517   0  7:19PM ??         0:00.02 /private/tmp/gcc-20160805-32134-1wpoevg/gcc-6.1.0/build/./gcc/cc1 -quiet -I . -I . -I ../../.././gcc -I ../../../../libgcc -I ../../../../libgcc/. -I ../../../../libgcc/../gcc -I ../../../../libgcc/../include -imultilib i386 -iprefix /private/tmp/gcc-20160805-32134-1wpoevg/gcc-6.1.0/build/gcc/../lib/gcc/6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/6.1.0/ -isystem /private/tmp/gcc-20160805-32134-1wpoevg/gcc-6.1.0/build/./gcc/include -isystem /private/tmp/gcc-20160805-32134-1wpoevg/gcc-6.1.0/build/./gcc/include-fixed -MD trunctfxf2.d -MF trunctfxf2.dep -MP -MT trunctfxf2.o -D__DYNAMIC__ -D IN_GCC -D IN_LIBGCC2 -D HAVE_CC_TLS -D USE_EMUTLS -D HIDE_EXPORTS -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.1.0_1/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/include -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.1.0_1/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/sys-include -isystem ./include ../../../../libgcc/soft-fp/trunctfxf2.c -fPIC -feliminate-unused-debug-symbols -quiet -dumpbase trunctfxf2.c -m32 -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -mtune=core2 -auxbase-strip trunctfxf2.o -g -g -g -O2 -O2 -O2 -Wextra -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-type-limits -fbuilding-libgcc -fno-stack-protector -fno-common -fvisibility=hidden -o -
  503 38519 38516   0  7:19PM ??         0:00.03 (cc1)
  503 38524 38520   0  7:19PM ??         0:00.02 /private/tmp/gcc-20160805-32134-1wpoevg/gcc-6.1.0/build/./gcc/cc1 -quiet -I . -I . -I ../.././gcc -I ../../../libgcc -I ../../../libgcc/. -I ../../../libgcc/../gcc -I ../../../libgcc/../include -iprefix /private/tmp/gcc-20160805-32134-1wpoevg/gcc-6.1.0/build/gcc/../lib/gcc/6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/6.1.0/ -isystem /private/tmp/gcc-20160805-32134-1wpoevg/gcc-6.1.0/build/./gcc/include -isystem /private/tmp/gcc-20160805-32134-1wpoevg/gcc-6.1.0/build/./gcc/include-fixed -MD fixunstfti_s.d -MF fixunstfti_s.dep -MP -MT fixunstfti_s.o -D__DYNAMIC__ -D IN_GCC -D IN_LIBGCC2 -D HAVE_CC_TLS -D USE_EMUTLS -D SHARED -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.1.0_1/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/include -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.1.0_1/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/sys-include -isystem ./include ../../../libgcc/soft-fp/fixunstfti.c -fPIC -feliminate-unused-debug-symbols -quiet -dumpbase fixunstfti.c -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -mtune=core2 -auxbase-strip fixunstfti_s.o -g -g -g -O2 -O2 -O2 -Wextra -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-type-limits -fbuilding-libgcc -fno-stack-protector -fno-common -o -
  503 38532 12478   0  7:19PM ttys005    0:00.00 grep cc1
```

Answer (score 2):

`cc1` is part of Xcode, it's the compiler actually. Installation via Homebrew requires compilation, that's what's keeping your Mac busy here.

Comment: thanks. Can you explain me with more details? Why there are so much relative paths (../../) used?

Comment: @Fyodor that gets into the complexities of building code and is too broad for this site. There have been many books written. Start by learning C/objective C or C++ programming then learn how to build those apps